# Need help making my delete button work

Tags: database, python-3.x, sqlite

This is a section of my program for a contact book. When the user adds a contact it saves into my database that has 2 columns (Name & phone) and then shows in a treeview. NameEntry is the name of the entry field. I am trying to code a section so that when they click on a contact from my treeview then click delete, it will check for that name and then delete from the database. (After sqlite3.connect on line 3 i have the pathway for my database in my program)

```
def deleteData(self):

    db = sqlite3.connect 
    cursor = db.cursor()
    NameEntry = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())
    query = "DELETE FROM contacts WHERE Name = '%s';"%NameEntry
    cursor.execute(query)
    db.commit()
    cursor.close()
```

When i run it, i get this error (line 124 from my code correlates to line 7 on this piece of code):

```
    File "D:\Uni\Computing\newattempt2.py", line 124, in deleteData
    cursor.execute(query)
    sqlite3.OperationalError: near "text": syntax error
```

Comment: Can you put a `print(NameEntry)` right before the line with `cursor.execute(query)` and show us what the output is?

Comment: It still gives me the same error message when i click on my delete button.

Comment: OK, but what I'm looking for is the contents of the `NameEntry` variable. So if you're putting the `print` statement in the place I specified, then either you should get some other output in addition to the error message, or the exception is not being thrown by the code that you posted.

Comment: Its ok, I have solved it another way. What i was trying to do the first way was get the name the user clicks on and take it to match it with a name from the database. What I have done now is create an entry field to directly ask the user to enter the name of the contact they want to delete. Im a programming amateur so did not think of this before.